# How to reverse the process of np.flatten() and mapping?

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I have a target value numpy array with this format, lets say 10 dimensions (24,10)

```
Target = [[ 2,  0,  2,  0,  0,  3,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0, -2,  4, -2,  0,  0,
    -3, -3, -5,  1,  0,  0,  0,  2],...]
```

So I applied this map

```
checker_presence = {
5: np.array([1,1,1,1,1], dtype=int),
4: np.array([1,1,1,1,0], dtype=int),
3: np.array([1,1,1,0,0], dtype=int),
2: np.array([1,1,0,0,0], dtype=int),
1: np.array([1,0,0,0,0], dtype=int),
0: np.array([0,0,0,0,0], dtype=int),
-1: np.array([-1,0,0,0,0], dtype=int),
-2: np.array([-1,-1,0,0,0], dtype=int),
-3: np.array([-1,-1,-1,0,0], dtype=int),
-4: np.array([-1,-1,-1,-1,0], dtype=int),
-5: np.array([-1,-1,-1,-1,-1], dtype=int)}

labels_ = np.array([list(map(checker_presence.__getitem__, row)) for row in target])
```

And the target value is now (10,24,5):

```
  [[ 1,  1,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 1,  1,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 1,  1,  1,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [-1, -1,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  0],
   [-1, -1,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [-1, -1, -1,  0,  0],
   [-1, -1, -1,  0,  0],
   [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
   [ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 1,  1,  0,  0,  0]],...]
```

After this I applied a flatten function to be only one single array (10,120):

```
labels = np.array([i.flatten() for i in labels_])
[ 1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
    0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
    0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
    0,  0,  0,  0, -1, -1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0, -1, -1,  0,
    0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1, -1, -1,  0,  0,
   -1, -1, -1,  0,  0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
    0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0,
    0],...]
```

My question is how I can reverse this process to my target value be the original

```
[ 2,  0,  2,  0,  0,  3,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0, -2,  4, -2,  0,  0,
-3, -3, -5,  1,  0,  0,  0,  2]
```

In this example I only use one row to better understanding. The problem is that I needed do this transformations for my neural network, but to analyze the predict, I need reverse the process.

Comment: What do you want to do if your network produces a pattern that is not in the list, like [1, 1, 1, 0, 1], say?

Comment: I suspect the mapping, in both directions, will be easier if the dictionary values were tuples rather than arrays.  Then you could construct a reverse dictionary.  Converting a (10,24,5) array to (10,120) and back is just a simple application of `np.reshape`.

Comment: You right and the flatten was unnecessary too, with reshape it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using advanced indexing for lookup which should be quite a bit faster than any dictionary based approach. I've also added a faster version of the forward map using this method. Btw. if you know that your network only produces legal patterns, then you can just reshape and then sum over the last axis to restore the original representation.

```
import numpy as np

checker_presence = {
5: np.array([1,1,1,1,1], dtype=int),
4: np.array([1,1,1,1,0], dtype=int),
3: np.array([1,1,1,0,0], dtype=int),
2: np.array([1,1,0,0,0], dtype=int),
1: np.array([1,0,0,0,0], dtype=int),
0: np.array([0,0,0,0,0], dtype=int),
-1: np.array([-1,0,0,0,0], dtype=int),
-2: np.array([-1,-1,0,0,0], dtype=int),
-3: np.array([-1,-1,-1,0,0], dtype=int),
-4: np.array([-1,-1,-1,-1,0], dtype=int),
-5: np.array([-1,-1,-1,-1,-1], dtype=int)}

forward_lookup = np.empty((11, 5), int)
for k, v in checker_presence.items():
    forward_lookup[k] = v

reverse_lookup = np.full((3, 3, 3, 3, 3), 999999)
for k, v in checker_presence.items():
    reverse_lookup[(*v,)] = k

def forward(data, flatten=True):
    mapped = forward_lookup[data]
    return mapped.ravel() if flatten else mapped

def reverse(mapped, shape=(-1,), assume_all_legal=False):
    if assume_all_legal:
        return mapped.reshape(*shape, 5).sum(-1)
    return reverse_lookup[(*np.moveaxis(mapped.reshape(*shape, 5), -1, 0),)]

# small example

A = np.random.randint(-5, 6, (1, 5))
B = forward(A)
C = reverse(B, A.shape)
D = reverse(B, A.shape, True)

print(A)
print(B)
print(C)
print(D)

# large example

A = np.random.randint(-5, 6, (200, 1000))
B = forward(A)
C = reverse(B, A.shape)
D = reverse(B, A.shape, True)

assert np.all(A==C) and np.all(A==D)
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks. This is a masterpiece.

Answer (score 3):

While `flatten` collapses dimensions, `reshape` can do arbitrary dimensional transformations. It exist in both function and method form. Quick example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.empty((10, 24, 5))
b = a.reshape(10, 120)  # or b = np.reshape(a, (10, 120))
print(b.shape)  # shows (10, 120)
c = b.reshape(10, 24, 5)  # or c = np.reshape(b, (10, 24, 5))
print(c.shape)  # shows (10, 24, 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a nested list comprehension:

```
import numpy as np

labels = [ 1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
    0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
    0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
    0,  0,  0,  0, -1, -1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0, -1, -1,  0,
    0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1, -1, -1,  0,  0,
   -1, -1, -1,  0,  0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
    0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0,
    0]

checker_presence = {
5: np.array([1,1,1,1,1], dtype=int),
4: np.array([1,1,1,1,0], dtype=int),
3: np.array([1,1,1,0,0], dtype=int),
2: np.array([1,1,0,0,0], dtype=int),
1: np.array([1,0,0,0,0], dtype=int),
0: np.array([0,0,0,0,0], dtype=int),
-1: np.array([-1,0,0,0,0], dtype=int),
-2: np.array([-1,-1,0,0,0], dtype=int),
-3: np.array([-1,-1,-1,0,0], dtype=int),
-4: np.array([-1,-1,-1,-1,0], dtype=int),
-5: np.array([-1,-1,-1,-1,-1], dtype=int)}

chunked = [labels[i:i + 5] for i in range(0, len(labels), 5)]

target = [key for chunk in chunked for key, value in checker_presence.items() if list(value)==chunk]
```

Yields:

```
[2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -2, 4, -2, 0, 0, -3, -3, -5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll check with more than one dimension